# What does SDL_opengl do?

Tags: opengl, sdl-2

This is a broader question, so I'll narrow it down. From online tutorials, I've pieced together that SDL has a library called SDL_opengl that helps with openGL loading. However, it doesn't seem to actually contain openGL itself. But I might be wrong.

What does SDL_opengl do? Why would I include it over GLEW or platform-specific GL implementations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After working with it for a while, it seems like SDL_opengl is just a replacement for the older GL/gl.h libraries.